# How can I get dynamically input field id in jquery on button click and save to another button.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**I am totally fresher in JavaScript and jQuery can anyone help me or suggest  regarding this task how can I do this.**

**I have a task, I want want get dynamic id of input field on button click, I have 100 dynamic input field**

```
<input id="ProgressBar_1" type="text" name="dProgressBar_1" class="form-control bulk-pricing-streetProgressBar">

<input id="ProgressBar_2" type="text" name="dProgressBar_2" class="form-control bulk-pricing-streetProgressBar">
```

**these are my id's, I want to get these id's on button click there code I have mention below.**

```
<button type="button" class="btn fa fa-arrow-right next-stepBulkProgressBar btn-success __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" id=" "></button>
```

**Finally I want store these getting id's in another button.**

```
<button id="" class="btn btn-danger handleIncorrectNoBtn" type="button">Remove House</button>

Finally I  Want to perform some task on this button.
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried, or debugging it will be pretty hard. (SO isn't here to write your application for you)

Comment: Please post your javascript code

Comment: How the button and those inputs are related

Comment: Finally I want store these getting id's in another button??

Comment: where its can be store??

Comment: It can be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ill give you a couple of hints, though i find it very hard to fully understand what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe rewrite your question, provide some specifics and be more clear if possible.

[From what i understand]
your first part is a button that when clicked will retrieve the ids of input fields?

lets say this is your button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn fa fa-arrow-right next-stepBulkProgressBar btn-success __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" id="myButton"></button>
```

the click code would look similar to (i'm kind of pseudo coding this af you have provided no example or demo i can use to test, my apologies if this is not correct):

```
function {

var ids = [];

    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
      ids = [];
      $("input .classOnAllInputIdsYouWantToGet").each(function(e){
         ids.push(e.attr("id"));
      });
      // store in a variable here or continue using the ids variable 
      // created above - this can be used anywhere within this function
    });

    function myOtherFunctionINeedIds(){
        // Use ids here
     }
}
```

im not sure if this is what you are after, if not please update or amend your question and i will change my answer to try get exactly what you are after.

good luck.